# a simple way to expire an activation link in php?

Tags: php, mysql

just need a simple way to expire an activation link which is sent to the users on my site via email. currently the date that users registered stored in mysql database.
the link that's sent in the email is like this: /activation.php?id=20

this is my activation

```
    <? 
include_once "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
// Get the member id from the URL variable
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$id = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $id); // filter everything but numbers for security
if (!$id) {
    echo "Missing Data to Run";
    exit(); 
}
// Update the database field named 'email_activated' to 1
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET emailactivated='1' WHERE id='$id'"); 
// Check the database to see if all is right now 
$sql_doublecheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id='$id' AND emailactivated='1'"); 
$doublecheck = mysql_num_rows($sql_doublecheck); 
if($doublecheck == 0){ 
// Print message to the browser saying we could not activate them
print "<br /><br /><div align=\"center\"><h3><strong><font color=red>Your account could not be activated!</font></strong><h3><br /></div>"; 
} elseif ($doublecheck > 0) {
// Print a success message to the browser cuz all is good 
// And supply the user with a link to your log in page, please alter that link line 
print "<br /><br /><h3><font color=\"#0066CC\"><strong>Your account has been activated!<br /><br />
</strong></font><a href=\"\">Click Here</a> to log in now.</h3>"; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: yes, it is. sorry. I couldn't post my entire code on that one. i do apologies for duplicate posts.

Comment: Some other general tips `ereg_*` functions, `<font>` tags are depreciated and MOST IMPORTANTLY `mysql_query` are NOT RECOMMENDED anymore use `PDO` functions or `mysqli` functions

Answer (score 1):

when you create the activation link, store a unix timestamp with it in its record in the table

a table may look like:

```
activation_links
id,link_hash,created_date,expiration_date,is_active,used_date
```

then on activation just check against the expiration date

```
$key = $_GET['key'];
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM activation_links WHERE link_hash = '$key' AND expiration_date <= ".time();
```

Furthermore, you do not want to use simple numeric activation keys. You should generate long random strings that can't easily be guessed.

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

**SIDE NOTE:**
You should be using either MySQLi or PDO

ex.

```
$db = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);
```

Comment: Thanks alot. wow that is alot of info for me to digest. I am no expert like you guys. just learning the basics. :) any chance you could explain the first two codes you've posted in simple terms so i can understand it please?

Comment: The first code block is a sample layout of a table in a database that would store the generated activation links. The second code block would check to see if the activation link exists in the database that has an expiration date less than the current time. You would also want to check to make sure that it has not been used, or delete it from the db after it is used.

Comment: so how can i expire the link after 24 hours? the codes above confuse me because they do not contain any of the table or column names i used in my activation.php and my mysql database!! I thought there must be any simple  or simpler explanation with codes to follow  about this!?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an activation expiration date field on your members table in your database. That way, when you create the member record, insert the date that is, for example, 6 hours in advance. Then when the link click is processed, make sure the activation date has not yet passed.

Comment: is there any tutorial(s) that you guys know of so i can learn the procedure like that?